# (NumPy) Swap largest and smallest, swap 2nd largest and 2nd smallest, ..., swap nth largest and nth smallest, for all n, in 1D array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

For example, given the arrays

```
vector1 = np.array([111, 1, 11, 1111])
vector2 = np.array([2222, 2, 222, 22, 22222])
```

I want to find the permutations such

```
np.all(vector1[permutation1] == np.array([11, 1111, 111,1]))
np.all(vector2[permutation2] == np.array([22, 22222, 222, 2222, 2]))
```

such that the n'th largest value is replaced by the n'th smallest value for any n.

It's clear (albeit tedious) how to compute these permutations by hand for these specific examples, we have

```
permutation1 = np.array([2, 3, 0, 1])
permutation2 = np.array([3, 4, 2, 0, 1])
```

I thought going into this that some combination of `np.argsort` and `np.flip` should work. However, I have not been able to find any such combination, and there seems to be something more basic that I am missing.

**What I have tried so far:**
I know `np.argsort` can be used to invert a permutation, so e.g.
`np.all(np.argsort(np.argsort(permutation)) == permuation)`
and
`np.all(np.argsort(np.argsort(np.argsort(vector))) == np.argsort(vector))`
are both always `True`.

`np.argsort(np.argsort(vector))` gives the permutation explaining what the relative order of each element in the original vector is, for example

```
np.all(np.argsort(np.argsort(vector1)) == np.array([2, 0, 1, 3]))
```

which correctly says that the first element of `vector1` is the 2nd largest, the second element of `vector1` is the smallest, the third element is the 2nd smallest, the fourth element is the largest.

However, `np.argsort(np.argsort(np.flip(vector)))` does not work as I had expected it to (and it also equals `np.flip(np.argsort(np.argsort(vector)))`. Neither do `np.argsort(np.flip(np.argsort(vector)))` nor `np.flip(np.argsort(np.flip(vector)))`. At this point I doubt `np.flip` is the right function to use but I am somewhat at a loss otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
>>> arr
array([ 111,    1,   11, 1111])
>>> np.sort(arr)[::-1][np.argsort(np.argsort(arr))]
array([  11, 1111,  111,    1])
```

Comment: You're a lifesaver! Thank you so much! I need to work out the math/logic of why this works myself, but it definitely does seem to work. Thank you again!

Comment: OK, because `np.sort(vector)[np.argsort(np.argsort(vector))]` is the same as `vector` (because `np.argsort(np.argsort(vector))` is the inverse of `np.argsort(vector)`), the value of `np.argsort(np.argsort(vector))` at position `i` (e.g. `5`) says that `vector[i]` is the `(5+1)`'th smallest element. So in order to get the `(5+1)`th _largest_ element at position `i`, we just index `np.flip(np.sort(vector))` or equivalently `np.sort(vector)[::-1]` instead. This makes sense and definitely should always work. Thank you again!